# There is a difference between using Json or Metadata working with Structured Data?

Tags: json, metadata, structured-data

I'm implementing Structured Data at a website, And I saw that I can use the Json to implement my Rich Cards on my page. Before this I was using:

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="http://site.com.br/">

<!--google-->
<meta itemprop="name" content="SITE eXEMPLE">
<meta itemscope="" itemtype="http://www.site.com.br/">
<meta itemprop="headline" content="Description of a SITE FOR | Exemple">
<!-- And that's it -->
```

There is a difference on performance or reading of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the snippet, you are using RDFa (`property`) and Microdata (`itemprop` etc.). Together with JSON-LD, these are the three syntaxes supported by Schema.org’s sponsors (the big search engines).

Each syntax has its own advantages/disadvantages (see my answer about [differences between JSON-LD, Microdata, and RDFa](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/328711/63183)), but they are all capable of conveying the same structured data. So if a consumer supports all of them, just choose whichever works best for you.

Comment: Thank you, I'm a bit lost, but I've been crawling your answer, and I found a light at the end of the tunnel. :p ... I think i'm on the right way now.